# Heroku - Push rejected on Laravel 4.2 project Mcrypt error

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I 'm trying to upload my project laravel 4.2, using the buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php and get the following output.

```
Counting objects: 88, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (74/74), done.
Writing objects: 100% (88/88), 1010.88 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 88 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/php
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: 
remote:  !     WARNING: Your 'composer.lock' is not up to date with the latest
remote:        changes in 'composer.json'. To ensure you are not getting stale
remote:        dependencies, run 'composer update' on your machine and commit
remote:        any changes to Git before pushing again.
remote: 
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing system packages...
remote:        NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.json; requirements
remote:        from dependencies in composer.lock will be used for selection
remote:        - php (7.0.2)
remote:        - Apache (2.4.16)
remote:        - Nginx (1.8.0)
remote: -----> Enabling PHP extensions...
remote:        - ext-pcntl (composer.lock)
remote:        - ext-zend-opcache (automatic)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.0.0-alpha11 2015-11-14 16:21:07
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:        Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.8.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/finder (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/console (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.12)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing stack/builder (v1.0.3)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing predis/predis (v0.8.7)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (0.3.10)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing patchwork/utf8 (v1.3.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.17.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.17.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing nikic/php-parser (v0.9.5)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing filp/whoops (1.1.10)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.10)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.8.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing laravel/framework (v4.2.18)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > php artisan clear-compiled
remote:        Mcrypt PHP extension required.
remote:        Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
remote:        
remote:        
remote:                              
remote:          [RuntimeException]  
remote:          Error Output:       
remote:                              
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:        
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fzamudio.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fzamudio.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fzamudio.git'
```

It is the project by default

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel fzamudio 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

I do not change anything, just remove composer.lock from .gitignore, add Procfile with

```
web : vendor / bin / php- apache2 - heroku public
```

and init git.

I already did the composer update and it did not work.

From already thank you very much.